# css dashed border with <h1> tag AND image inside

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to make a coupon-type dashed border with `<h1>` text and an image inside. I am able to create the text, but can't figure out how to also get the picture in there, too.

I am using blogger because I don't really know how to code. Here's what I have so far:

```
<style>h1 {border-style: dashed;
background-color:coral;}</style>
<h1>Never Pay Full Price for Summer Camp Again. Get Free Coupons, Discount & Special Offers from CampCoupons.com!</h1>
```

I'd love to get an image inside the border, too, but can't figure out how.

Comment: Don't forget to post what you tried so far.

Comment: share your html code

Comment: yes share your HTML and CSS code snippet. that will help us to understand the your problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

An image is not semantically a heading and should not be placed within a h1 (or any other hN tag). Rather use a wrapping section/aside/div (depending on your use case) to combine a heading with an image like below.

```css
.wrap {
  background: coral;
  border: dashed;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<img src="http://placehold.it/400/200/" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to "put" your image in the `<h1>` using `background-image` and `background-position` in CSS like this :

```css
#test{
  border : 1px dashed black;
  background-image : url('https://bcs-solution.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Logo_Develop-H100-250x100.jpg;');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  background-position:0px 15px;
  width: 255px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="test">
My title 1
</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you see this one I think This is useful for you.

```css
h1 {
  border-style: dashed; 
  background-color: coral;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <h1>h1 heading text</h1>
```

Comment: @Eric N, Where you want image below h1 tag or else in h1 tag background.